# How to put wait in mocha nodejs

Tags: node.js, testing, timeout, wait

CODE -

```
.then (() => {
            console.log("Wait");
            setTimeout(function(){console.log("Wait to process")},1500);        
            this.timeout(2000);     
          })
.then(() => {
            console.log("Get ABC");
            return common.getApiData(url)})
```

Now when i run this code it logs data like -
Wait
Get ABC
Wait to process 
(The it waits for the time specified above)

I want to put timeout before calling getApiData method..

Comment: What kind of thenable are these? The function passed in `then` of a A+ Promise should take the value of the previous resolved promise and return a new promise.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing  you are using real promises, this is the function you should pass to `then`:

```
.then(function (value) {
    var p = new Promise ();
    setTimeout (function () {
       p.resolve(value)
    }, 2000) 
    return p
})
```

The next `then` will be called once the promise is resolved.